# Need help to show two arrays in one table

Tags: javascript, node.js

There are 2 option
My database is constructed like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ecbb3be949603f122dfcc4"),
    "work_id" : 651853,
    "date" : ISODate("2017-04-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-04-11T11:17:42.067Z"),
    "name" : "John Doe",
    "wage_type" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58ecbb567f7ed00c2ca041b6"),
            "type_ident" : "157",
            "start_string" : "020000",
            "start_time" : "02:00:00",
            "total" : "08:00:00",
            "end_time" : "09:59:59",
            "end_string" : "095959",
            "group" : "Wage Type<br/>",
            "end_date" : "2017-04-10",
            "type" : "Morning Hours",
            "start_date" : "2017-04-10",
            "time_sheet_ident" : "248288"
        }
    ],
    "campaign" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58ecbb567f7ed00c2ca041b5"),
            "type_ident" : "165",
            "start_string" : "020000",
            "start_time" : "02:00:00",
            "total" : "08:00:00",
            "end_time" : "09:59:59",
            "end_string" : "095959",
            "group" : "Campaign<br/>",
            "end_date" : "2017-04-10",
            "type" : "Waitter",
            "start_date" : "2017-04-10",
            "time_sheet_ident" : "248288"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0,
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-04-11T11:17:13.182Z")
}
```

But I find 2 difficulties
First when an worker has this structure

Based on user wage

```
John Doe | Morning Hours | 4.00-12.00
```

Based on user campaign

```
John Doe | Waiter | 4.00-8.00
John Doe | Bartender | 8.00-12.00
```

And this is the other option

```
Jim Dow | Morning Hours | 9.00-16.00
JIm Dow | Night Hours | 16-18
```

Based on campaign

```
Jim Dow | Waitter | 9.00-18.00
```

What i could do till now is when the have the same start time and end time so i pass the campaign in which he worked on

The difficult part which i cant find out is when they are 2 john doe on database on different campaigns or 2 jim dow on 2 different timesheets

If u can help me thanks in advance

Comment: _"If u can help me"_ is not a question. Please add a clear problem statement, and a [mcve] of you issue.

Comment: @evolutionxbox what else do u want me to show to you

Comment: My previous comment states what I think will help more people try and answer your question.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @evolutionxbox U dont have to do nothing? Go work man

Comment: I'm taking time out from my day (and job) to try and help. I'm not here to write a complete solution for free. It doesn't help you nor me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it on my won
for (let i = 0; i < timesheets.length; i++) {

```
                if (timesheets[i].wage_type !== 'none' && timesheets[i].wage_type || timesheets[i].campaign !== 'none' && timesheets[i].campaign ) {
                    for (let j = 0; j < timesheets[i].wage_type.length; j++) {
                        for (let k = 0; k < timesheets[i].campaign.length; k++){





                            if(timesheets[i].wage_type[j].start_time == timesheets[i].campaign[k].start_time && timesheets[i].wage_type[j].end_time == timesheets[i].campaign[k].end_time && timesheets[i].wage_type[j].time_sheet_ident == timesheets[i].campaign[k].time_sheet_ident ) {
                                 const temp = {};
                                 temp.ccms_id = timesheets[i].ccms_id;
                                 temp.date = timesheets[i].date;
                                 temp.name = timesheets[i].name;
                                 temp.campaign = timesheets[i].campaign[k].type;
                                 temp.type = timesheets[i].wage_type[j].type;
                                 temp.start_time = timesheets[i].wage_type[j].start_time;
                                 temp.end_time = timesheets[i].wage_type[j].end_time;
                                 temp.total = timesheets[i].wage_type[j].total;
                                 wages.push(temp);
                            }
                            else if (timesheets[i].wage_type[j].start_time <= timesheets[i].campaign[k].start_time && timesheets[i].wage_type[j].end_time >= timesheets[i].campaign[k].end_time ){
                                 const temp = {};
                                 temp.ccms_id = timesheets[i].ccms_id;
                                 temp.date = timesheets[i].date;
                                 temp.name = timesheets[i].name;
                                 temp.campaign = timesheets[i].campaign[k].type;
                                 temp.type = timesheets[i].wage_type[j].type;
                                 temp.start_time = timesheets[i].campaign[k].start_time;
                                 temp.end_time = timesheets[i].campaign[k].end_time;
                                 temp.total = timesheets[i].campaign[k].total;
                                 wages.push(temp);
                             }
                            else if (timesheets[i].wage_type[j].start_time >= timesheets[i].campaign[k].start_time && timesheets[i].wage_type[j].end_time <= timesheets[i].campaign[k].end_time ){
                                 const temp = {};
                                 temp.ccms_id = timesheets[i].ccms_id;
                                 temp.date = timesheets[i].date;
                                 temp.name = timesheets[i].name;
                                 temp.campaign = timesheets[i].campaign[k].type;
                                 temp.type = timesheets[i].wage_type[j].type;
                                 temp.start_time = timesheets[i].wage_type[j].start_time;
                                 temp.end_time = timesheets[i].wage_type[j].end_time;
                                 temp.total = timesheets[i].wage_type[j].total;
                                 wages.push(temp);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```